# CSS hide text (without taking space) but not child element

Tags: html, css, visibility

I have created this fiddle to demonstrate the problem I'm having:
https://jsfiddle.net/gpb5wx8h/

```
<button id="add-redirect" class="ui-button ui-widget ui-corner-all ui-state-default" name="add-redirect" value="add-redirect" type="submit">
    <span class="ui-button-text">
        <i class="fa fa-plus">visible</i> not visible
    </span>
</button>
<style>
    button .ui-button-text {
        visibility: collapse
    }
    button .ui-button-text i.fa {
        visibility: visible
    }
</style>
```

As you can see in the fiddle, the text is indeed not visible, exactly what I want, but it's still taking up space in my button, exactly what I don't want.

I can't change the HTML, so altering the layout is not an option.

I'd like the text to be completely invisible and not taking up any space in the element at all. At the same time, child element should be visible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`visibility: collapse;` is only for table elements. collapse removes a row or column, but it does not affect the table layout. The space taken up by the row or column will be available for other content.
In your case, you can simply use this trick:

```css
button .ui-button-text {
    font-size:0
}
button .ui-button-text i.fa {
    font-size:12px;
}
```

```html
<button id="add-redirect" class="ui-button ui-widget ui-corner-all ui-state-default" name="add-redirect" value="add-redirect" type="submit"><span class="ui-button-text"><i class="fa fa-plus">visible</i> not visible</span></button>
```

Answer (score 3):

Use `font-size` for button - **no need to define visiblity.**

```
button .ui-button-text {
    font-size: 0;
}

button .ui-button-text i.fa {
    font-size: 14px; // choose font size you want
}
```

Comment: `visibility` is redundant here. In fact, `visibility collapse` is applied only for `...table rows, columns, column groups, and row groups`.

Comment: Okay, so don't use the visibility like that. Just to be sure, is setting the font-size to 0 considered as bad practice?

Answer (score 1):

Check if [this](https://jsfiddle.net/gpb5wx8h/2/) solution helps. Requires a bit of structure change in html.

**CSS:**

```
button .ui-button-text i.fa {
    display:block;
}
button .ui-button-text i{
  display:none;
}
```

Comment: I have no control over the HTML output, so I can't just add an additional element as in your fiddle.

Comment: This is just a workaround for your case as html can't be controlled. In case if text increases you need to readjust css. https://jsfiddle.net/gpb5wx8h/4/

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps you

```css
button .ui-button-text {
    visibility: collaps
}
button .ui-button-text i.fa {
    visibility: visible
}
button{
max-width: 60px;
overflow: hidden;
height:23px;
}
```

```html
<button id="add-redirect" class="ui-button ui-widget ui-corner-all ui-state-default" name="add-redirect" value="add-redirect" type="submit">
  <span class="ui-button-text">
    <i class="fa fa-plus">visible</i> not visible
  </span>
 </button>
```

Thanks